# Adjust css variable to increase size of css graphic

Tags: html, css

Often time I found myself failed to adjust the size of a graphical asset if it's in css. Any tool or tip how to do that?

For example I found this checker http://jsfiddle.net/awayF/491/

```
<span class="checkmark">
    <div class="checkmark_circle"></div>
    <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
    <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
</span>
```

I might spend more than 10 min trying to adjust here and there.

Comment: Are you tying to adjust the size of the checkmark? Or are you trying to change the size of any asset with a variable dynamically?

Comment: Can You explain exactly what you want ?

Comment: Just use images. It is easier to implement and no cross browser issues. Also, it is more widely used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale and translate the `checkmark` container using the same transform property

**Note:transform property may not be support by certain browsers version**

see

```css
.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4,4); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4,4); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4,4) translate(20px);;

}

.checkmark_circle {
    position: absolute;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius:11px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#fff;
    left:11px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:3px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#fff;
    left:8px;
    top:12px;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkmark">
    <div class="checkmark_circle"></div>
    <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
    <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: this is slick and smart, tq!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the zoom property

```
.checkmark { zoom: 20; }
```

this will scale it 2000%

Comment: -moz-transform: scale(20); should be the equivalent

Comment: 1: Nothing in your answer suggest that 2: Just adding scale will not work as zoom does (try and you'll see) 3: -mox- prefix were dropped in 2012

Comment: not sure if -webkit-transform: scale(20, 20); would work, haven't used firefox in awhile :/

Answer (score 1):

If you size child elements using percent, you just simply set a size to the parent, in this case the `.checkmark`, and they grow with it.

When done like this, the circle will flow properly as the transform occurs on the inner pseudo element.

```css
.checkmark {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
.checkmark2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.checkmark_circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.checkmark_circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 25%;
  border-left: 8px solid white;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -70%) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(-45%, -70%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate(-45%, -70%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="checkmark">
    <div class="checkmark_circle"></div>
</span>
<span class="checkmark2">
    <div class="checkmark_circle"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: I know but often time I found interesting art work which isn't done by me. I just wonder how can I take it and modify it seamlessly.

Comment: @JessicaIlly Got that, and here you have a few answers showing some options, just consider my suggestion when you reuse others, and check so it is made clever or else you pay the price ... the sample you found I cut down to 50% of its original code, and that give your code the best feature of them all, performance

Comment: Gave u an upvote, imagine some complex vector has more than 80 lines of code.

Comment: @JessicaIlly Thanks ... and for those you use `scale` as _repzero_ posted :)